# pdflatex amd Matlab LaTeX interpreter alternative to psfrag?

Tags: pdftex, matlab, psfrag

I use TexWorks that comes together with Tex Live 2012. After having read a lot on how to use "something similar" to `psfrag` with `pdflatex`, I have almost found my way. I have just discovered the instruction `set(legend_name,'Interpreter','latex')` to set a LaTeX interpreter to read what we write in the legend directly. I found it very cool!

Next, I want to include a reference in the legend (or a citation). I use the standard command `\cite{bib_key}` when I write the legend in Matlab, but what I get as output is the typical "[?]" since LaTeX cannot find the bib-entry. I have tried to compile with BibTex, but nothing happens. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Using a command like `\cite` directly in MATLAB is a major pain. For example, if you just wanted to recreate the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
A citation: \cite{article-minimal}
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{xampl}}}
\end{document}
```

As I explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98760/including-package-to-create-matlab-labels-using-latex) of mine, if in MATLAB you define

```
legend_name = '\bibliographystyle{plain}A citation: \cite{article-minimal}\newsavebox\mytempbib\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{xampl}}}';
```

then the MATLAB LaTeX interpreter would convert it into

```
\nofiles
\documentclass{mwarticle}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\bibliographystyle{plain}%
A citation: \cite{article-minimal}%
\newsavebox\mytempbib%
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{xampl}}}%
}\copy0\special{bounds: \the\wd0 \the\ht0 \the\dp0}
\end{document}
```

where the `mwarticle` class is essentially the `article` class without sizing commands and margins. The `\nofiles`, along with not being able to find xampl.bib, causes this to fail. Even if you rewrite `tex.m` to not insert the `\nofiles`, you still have the issue of needing BibTex and multiple passes. The underlying MATLAB `texmex` function is closed source so modifying it to handle BibTex and multiple passes would be difficult and probably violate the MATLAB EULA.

The easiest option would probably be to overload `tex.m` to read a [dvi file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125470/10038). You can either reprogram `tex.m` to call your locally installed LaTeX engine, or simply make it use an already existing dvi file.

```
function [dviout,errout,auxout] = tex(varargin)
    fid = fopen('test.dvi');
    dviout = fread(fid, 'uint8');
    dviout = uint8(dviout);
    fclose(fid);
    errout = [];
    auxout = [];
end
```

If you then create test.dvi

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\topmargin{-0.5in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\bibliographystyle{plain}
A citation: \cite{article-minimal}
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{xampl}}}
}\copy0\special{bounds: \the\wd0 \the\ht0 \the\dp0}
\end{document}
```

You then get the result you want in MATLAB

```
plot(1:10);
legend({'DOES NOT MATTER'}, 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX')
```

A more robust, but more complicated solution, would be to fully hack `tex.m` to call `latex` and `bibtex` for you and handle the multiple passes.

Comment: I see. I thought it was something simpler to do, but I don't feel to hack any of the existing Matlab files (i.e. tex.m). I rather keep the originals. Well, at this point I will write the number of citation by hand, like `legend('Method in [11]', 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX')` without using any \cite command when defining the legend in Matlab. I have also tried to use .eps files together with XeLaTex, but it didn't work out.